# Web Service not runs two services in parallel

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, soap-client

I have an application with several Web Services. This system, classes were made to simplify the sending of requests.

My problem is: 
If a service takes to respond, the next service / request is queued, waiting for the first to finish.

Is there any way this does not happen?

I think this code snippet can be generated the problem to queue processes.

```
internal void SetServiceInProgress(SoapHttpClientProtocol service)
{
    lock (_serviceInProgressLock)
    {
        _serviceInProgress= service;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe taking a look at Asynchronous design would help, the SOAPHttpClientProtocol has begininvoke.  It would be my first start.

using a lock in code is designed to stop anything else accessing a an object until that lock is released, where it has its place in multithreaded/parallel programming, I believe you are misunderstanding its function.

have a look at
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soaphttpclientprotocol.begininvoke(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: How am I doing code maintenance, and the person who made the code is no longer in business, will know what went on in his head. But from what I understand the code is: block the process until the process finishes first, is this it? I have another problem, I can not change the web service server, because it is from another company, I have to turn around in the client.

Comment: yes, and any other attempts will wait until it is completed.
I would set up a test request and see if you can run 2 Separate requests as tasks at the same time, Maybe they know something about the other server, maybe it really struggles with multiple requests (would be an awful design mind you).
personally, I would look into task pooling, this way you can change the maximum processes with ease, or try and convert the existing task code to run asynchronously and just handle it's completed event.

please note that this advice is based on your information, there may be a good reason for that lock

Answer (score 0):

As explained by Duffy, Async call is the best solution for your program. This will let you to call each webservice independent of other and then you can use callback function to implement any logic on completion of a service. I am using it in my current project and it makes life easier when you have big application.